# Binary Grid Challenge and X & O Conundrum

Tags: grid-deduction, combinatorics, logic-grid, construction

You are given a 5x5 grid with some cells filled with either "X" or "O". Your goal is to fill the remaining cells with "X" or "O" following these rules:

Each row and column must contain exactly three "X"s and two "O"s.
No adjacent cells (horizontally or vertically) can have the same symbol

Comment: It seems clearly impossible to make any grid that fits the constraints. Is that your question?

Comment: The only possible two-symbol grid where no adjacent cells can have the same symbol is a checkerboard.

Answer (score 5):

No matter what the initial grid is ...

> it is impossible to fill the grid with the given constraints.
>
>  Since each row and column must contain exactly three "X"s and two "O"s and no adjacent cells (horizontally or vertically) can have the same symbol,
>  each row is forced to be exactly XOXOX which means the first column is forced to be XXXXX and that violates the given constraints.